# How do I define an IPv6 address with netplan on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, ubuntu-17.10

I'm trying to configure an interface with ipv6 with netplan on ubuntu 17.10.
Whe I use
netplan apply
the error is:

Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 7 column 23: found unexpected ':'

The yaml file is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      addresses: [ 2a02:ab8:0307:1:1/48 ]
      gateway6: 2a02:ab8:0307::1
      nameservers:
          search: [ oesterweb.at ]
          addresses:
              - 2a02:ab8:4::1
    ens19:
      addresses: [ 10.10.1.1/11 ]
      gateway4: 10.10.1.100
      nameservers:
          search: [ oesterweb.at ]
          addresses:
              - 10.10.1.100
      routes:
        - to: 10.33.0.0/24
```

What is the issue with ipv6 addresses in netplan. I can't find any information about this issue.

THX for your help!

Comment: That's strange. Line 7 doesn't have a column 23 with a `:` on it. But line 8 does. Regardless, the docs say that's perfectly valid, so I suspect you've found some sort of bug.

Comment: THX - yes there is an bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcfg/+bug/1751151